# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle in Room Migration

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made a mistake when establishing a relationship in my database, my application is already in production, so I must: increase the version number of my database and perform the corresponding migration (from version 1 to version 2 in my case).

2 tables will be affected:

1. CalificacionInterna

- Column "origen" will be eliminated
- Column "id_evento_int" will be added

2. Evento

- Column "id_calificacion_int_evento" will be deleted

[image]

This is my code for the migration:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        //Evento
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE EventoNew (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, categoria INTEGER, nombre TEXT, descripcion TEXT, fecha TEXT, hora TEXT, estatus INTEGER, id_semestre_ev INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(id_semestre_ev) REFERENCES Semestre(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO EventoNew (_id, categoria, nombre, descripcion, fecha, hora, estatus, id_semestre_ev) SELECT _id, categoria, nombre, descripcion, fecha, hora, estatus, id_semestre_ev FROM Evento");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE Evento");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE EventoNew RENAME TO Evento");
        //CalificacionInterna
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CalificacionInternaNew (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, calificacion TEXT, nombre TEXT, fechaAlmacenamiento TEXT, porcentaje TEXT, detalles TEXT, id_subcategoria_cal INTEGER, id_categoria_cal_int INTEGER, id_parcial_int INTEGER, id_asignatura_int INTEGER, id_evento_int INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(id_subcategoria_cal) REFERENCES Subcategoria(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_categoria_cal_int) REFERENCES CategoriaCal(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_parcial_int) REFERENCES Parcial(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_asignatura_int) REFERENCES Asignatura(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(id_evento_int) REFERENCES Evento(_id) ON DELETE CASCADE)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO CalificacionInternaNew (_id, calificacion, nombre, fechaAlmacenamiento, porcentaje, detalles, id_subcategoria_cal, id_categoria_cal_int, id_parcial_int, id_asignatura_int) SELECT _id, calificacion, nombre, fechaAlmacenamiento, porcentaje, detalles, id_subcategoria_cal, id_categoria_cal_int, id_parcial_int, id_asignatura_int FROM CalificacionInterna");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE CalificacionInterna");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CalificacionInternaNew RENAME TO CalificacionInterna");
    }
};
```

Basically

- I create a new table with the necessary columns
- Copy the necessary information
- Delete the previous table and rename the new table

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.calificaciones, PID: 4819
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.calificaciones/com.calificaciones.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: CalificacionInterna(com.calificaciones.entity.Calificacion).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='CalificacionInterna', columns={calificacion=Column{name='calificacion', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_subcategoria_cal=Column{name='id_subcategoria_cal', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, fechaAlmacenamiento=Column{name='fechaAlmacenamiento', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_asignatura_int=Column{name='id_asignatura_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, detalles=Column{name='detalles', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, porcentaje=Column{name='porcentaje', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_categoria_cal_int=Column{name='id_categoria_cal_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_parcial_int=Column{name='id_parcial_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, nombre=Column{name='nombre', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_evento_int=Column{name='id_evento_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Subcategoria', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_subcategoria_cal], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Parcial', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_parcial_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Evento', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_evento_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='CategoriaCal', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_categoria_cal_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Asignatura', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_asignatura_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_CalificacionInterna__id', unique=false, columns=[_id]}]}
     Found:
E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='CalificacionInterna', columns={calificacion=Column{name='calificacion', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_subcategoria_cal=Column{name='id_subcategoria_cal', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, fechaAlmacenamiento=Column{name='fechaAlmacenamiento', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_asignatura_int=Column{name='id_asignatura_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, detalles=Column{name='detalles', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, porcentaje=Column{name='porcentaje', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_categoria_cal_int=Column{name='id_categoria_cal_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_parcial_int=Column{name='id_parcial_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, nombre=Column{name='nombre', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_evento_int=Column{name='id_evento_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Subcategoria', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_subcategoria_cal], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Evento', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_evento_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Asignatura', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_asignatura_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Parcial', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_parcial_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='CategoriaCal', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_categoria_cal_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}], indices=[]}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2872)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: CalificacionInterna(com.calificaciones.entity.Calificacion).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='CalificacionInterna', columns={calificacion=Column{name='calificacion', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_subcategoria_cal=Column{name='id_subcategoria_cal', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, fechaAlmacenamiento=Column{name='fechaAlmacenamiento', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_asignatura_int=Column{name='id_asignatura_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, detalles=Column{name='detalles', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, porcentaje=Column{name='porcentaje', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_categoria_cal_int=Column{name='id_categoria_cal_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_parcial_int=Column{name='id_parcial_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, nombre=Column{name='nombre', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_evento_int=Column{name='id_evento_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Subcategoria', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_subcategoria_cal], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Parcial', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_parcial_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Evento', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_evento_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='CategoriaCal', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_categoria_cal_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Asignatura', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_asignatura_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}], indices=[Index{name='index_CalificacionInterna__id', unique=false, columns=[_id]}]}
     Found:
E/AndroidRuntime: TableInfo{name='CalificacionInterna', columns={calificacion=Column{name='calificacion', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_subcategoria_cal=Column{name='id_subcategoria_cal', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, fechaAlmacenamiento=Column{name='fechaAlmacenamiento', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_asignatura_int=Column{name='id_asignatura_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, detalles=Column{name='detalles', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, porcentaje=Column{name='porcentaje', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_categoria_cal_int=Column{name='id_categoria_cal_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_parcial_int=Column{name='id_parcial_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, nombre=Column{name='nombre', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id_evento_int=Column{name='id_evento_int', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='Subcategoria', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_subcategoria_cal], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Evento', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_evento_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Asignatura', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_asignatura_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='Parcial', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_parcial_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}, ForeignKey{referenceTable='CategoriaCal', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[id_categoria_cal_int], referenceColumnNames=[_id]}], indices=[]}
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:338)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:476)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:281)
        at com.calificaciones.crud.SemestreDao_Impl.numeroDeSemestres(SemestreDao_Impl.java:360)
        at com.calificaciones.MainActivity.reparar(MainActivity.java:156)
        at com.calificaciones.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2742)
            ... 9 more
```

Everything seems to match, but the foreign keys despite putting them in the same order as in my @Entity class, they appear to me in a different order from **"Expected"** to **"Found"**

**"Expected:"**
Subcategoria, Parcial, Evento, CategoriaCal, Asignatura

**"Found:"**
Subcategoria, Evento, Asignatura, Parcial, CategoriaCal

I don't know if the problem is there, another difference is **"Expected:"** `indices=[Index{name='index_CalificacionInterna__id', unique=false, columns=[_id]}]` **"Found:"** `indices=[]`

I hope someone can guide me on what the problem is and how it can be solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, first try to put this:

`database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_EventoNew__id ON EventoNew(_id)");` after creating the table, but i got an error saying that the index already existed, later I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56063911/13452141) that it should be put after renaming the table and that solved my problem:

`database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_Evento__id ON Evento(_id)");`